# Eclipse IDE problem

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I configurate eclipse 3.8 for catkin workspace.
talker.cpp and listener.cpp (from examples) compile and work fine (build by eclipse), but herewith eclipse find few errors.
In talker:

```
LINE: ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise < std_msgs::String > ("chatter", 1000);


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
ros::Publisher advertise(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, bool)
ros::Publisher advertise(ros::AdvertiseOptions &)
ros::Publisher advertise(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, const boost::function<void (const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher &)> &, const boost::function<void (const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher &)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &, bool)
'   talker.cpp  /Project@build/[Source directory]/beginner_tutorials/src    line 45 Semantic Error
```

In listener:

```
LINE: ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatterCallback);


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(#0), #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(ros::SubscribeOptions &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(#0)const, #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &), #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &)const, #1 *, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(#0), const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(#0)const, const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &), const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (#1::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &)const, const boost::shared_ptr<#1> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (*)(#0), const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, void (*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &), const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, const boost::function<void (const boost::shared_ptr<const #0> &)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
ros::Subscriber subscribe(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, ?, const boost::function<void (#1)> &, const boost::shared_ptr<const void> &, const ros::TransportHints &)
'   listener.cpp    /Project@build/[Source directory]/beginner_tutorials/src    line 79 Semantic Error
```

What's the matter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105446/eclipse-ide-problem/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I see correctly, your Eclipse does not recognize ros libraries. Follow these steps to install the Kepler Eclipse and then do a cmake compilation in order to make it recognisable.

1. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ From the eclipse page, scroll down to C/C++ for Developers and download it. Then untar it and copy it into /opt folder.
2. Start eclipse by command

   /opt/eclipse/./eclipse
3. If it complaints for java, install openjdk-7-jre.
4. Now go right to your catkin workspace and create a ros package

   roscreate-pkg my_pkg_example roscpp
5. Make it eclipse project

   cd ~/catkin_ws/src/my_pkg_example/
   make eclipse-project
6. Now, go ahead and create the file src/myfile.cpp and edit cmake by adding something like this to the default cmake (Assuming your executable is in src directory)

   rosbuild_add_executable(my_pkg_example src/myfile.cpp)
7. On the terminal type

   cd ~/catkin_ws/src/my_pkg_example/
   cmake .
   make
8. The last thing to do now is to go to Eclipse and Project > Run & Debug Settings (or something like this I don't remember). Add C/C++ Application. Select binary file which is ~/catkin_ws/src/my_pkg_example/bin/my_pkg_example. Then hit Apply.

Now your file should be correct.

---

Originally posted by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) with karma: 181 on 2013-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2013-11-29**:
I followed a manual http://answers.ros.org/question/52013/catkin-and-eclipse/?answer=53090#post-id-53090 and Eclipse build the workspace successfully. But Eclipse issue errors above.

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-12-01**:
I don't know about your manual, but if you do a fresh start and do these steps, I can help you with any related problem. Cheers.

**Comment by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on 2014-01-22**:
Hey mozcelikors

I am using ROS Hydro and trying to import a ROS package into Eclipse Kepler. When I get to the step using "make eclipse-project" I keep getting this error

make: *** No rule to make target `eclipse-project'.  Stop.

Do you know why this happens? I would appreciate any tips.

Thanks
Mike

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2014-01-22**:
You have to execute make eclipse-project to a project that you've already created using "roscreate-pkg  roscpp. The folder should be like cd ~/catkin_ws/src/ , provided that your catkin workspace is in ~/catkin_ws.

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2014-01-22**:
If you assured that you havent done anything wrong there, I can ask a colleague of mine who had the same problem.

**Comment by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on 2014-01-23**:
I created my ROS package using catkin_create_pkg instead of roscreate_pkg. The project is located in the catkin_ws which is in the home directory. I am using ROS Hydro as well. I still do not know where the problem lies.

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-01-27**:
I am using as well ROS Hydro with Catkin on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with Eclipse.
I have the same problem.
Even after deleting the ecliplse project and the build and devel folder and running catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-01-27**:
By the way there is no command like "make eclipse-project"

**Comment by [kersm](https://answers.ros.org/users/11121/kersm/) on 2014-02-02**:
@Markus Bader did you find any Solution? Having the same troubles here with ROS Groovy Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and Eclipse Kepler. The above described approach using rosbuild worked in a previous test. But I should use the catkin approach and don't want to maintainance both approaches...

**Comment by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on 2014-02-03**:
Hey Markus, unfortunately I have not found a solution and continue to use a standard text editor to write my code. If I do come up with a solution I will get back to you.

**Comment by [kersm](https://answers.ros.org/users/11121/kersm/) on 2014-02-03**:
Hi everyone, meanwhile i found a workaround but not using eclipse any longer. I tried out qtcreator and it worked out of the box, just open the ~/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt as project there and everything (codecompletion, inline error marks, ...) works fine for me now...

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-02-03**:
Hi
Yes I found a solution. I am using kdevelop again. Just click import Project and select the CMakeFile in your worspace src Folder. If you get asked a build Folder point to the projects build folder.
Kdevelop is faster but not as stable as eclipse. :-)